# Ajax condition is not working in the jquery mobile phonegap

Tags: javascript

In Ajax the condition given to check the readystate and status is not working in the jquery mobile phonegap.I checked it by giving an alert message inside the condition. why? And I attached the code

```
 function checkLogin()
{
   // navigator.notification.alert("hiii");

    var username;
    var password;

    var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.onreadystatechange=function()
    {

       // alert("....."+x.responseText);
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
        {
            // alert(x.readyState+"  --- "+x.status);
            alert("hai checkLogin");
            var item=x.responseText.trim();
            alert("Message :"+item);

            if(item=="1")
            {
                window.location="home.html";
            }
        }
    }

    //alert("open");
x.open("POST", "http://localhost:8087/CarRental/com/selcar/getLogin.jsp?username="+document.getElementById('username').value+"&password="+document.getElementById('loginpaswrd').value, true);
x.send();
```

Comment: you have not initiated the request yet  by using `x.send()` neither you have used any http method like get,post

Comment: why don't you use fetch? Do you need IE11 support? If yes use a polyfill

Comment: Sorry , I don't know how to use fetch.Can you explain it?